# Unable to get the forecast_ets property of the worksheetfunction class

Tags: excel, vba, forecasting, worksheet-function

I've been trying to call the `Forecast.ETS` function from VBA code with `Application.WorksheetFunction`, however I'm getting the "unable to get the `forecast_ets` property of the worksheetfunction class error."

```
Sub test()

Cells(20, 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Forecast_ETS(Cells(5, 3).Value, _
                                           Range(Cells(5, 3), Cells(20, 3)), _
                                           Range(Cells(5, 2), Cells(20, 2)).Value)

End Sub
```

`Cells(5,3).Value` is a date, same as `Range(Cells(5,2),Cells(20,2)).Value`

`Range(Cells(5, 3), Cells(20, 3))` contains the historical values.

Comment: Maybe try removing that last `.Value`

Comment: check against each required condition here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.forecast_ets . There are quite a few specified.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It worked when i entered the fourth parameters which is the length of the periodicity (12 in my case because seasonality is annual in my data in months).

It is supposed to be optional but it seems it's not.